# How to create functional test for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

What is the best way create tests that include:

- set checkbox
- bush buttom
- etc.

for Ruby on Rails test environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` to do this.

See the guides for more information: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing

If you want a better html control you can use [capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) for this. (see the repo's README)

In your case the test would look something like this (with capybara):

```
class UiTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "select check box and push button" do 
    visit "/my-route"
    check "A Checkbox" # => you can use the label or the id here
    click_on "A button" # => here too.
  end
end
```

Make sure that you have it setup right! See: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-capybara-with-testunit